# Function looping when zero is entered

Tags: c, matrix, type-conversion

I have a user_get_movement_index function that prompts user to enter a position 0 to 8 as part of a tic-tac-toe game.

This movement index is passed to is_position_empty where it determines if the movement index is invalid or the movement index is already taken, both shows an error message and returns false to trigger a recursion of user_get_movement_index.

Functions loop correctly when the same number is entered twice, and behave as expected when any other number is entered but 0.

The problem is when 0 is entered its causes a loop of the error message of invalid position. 
I don't understand how it can be looping from within is_position_empty.
How is it not prompting user for input on each loop?
Why is 0 causing this loop?

Is it because we are comparing 0 < 0 in is_position_empty?

I'm new to C and stack overflow so please forgive my formatting, understanding and terrible code.

```
//--------------------------------------------------
// 05. FUNCTION my_getchar (IMPLEMENTED)
//--------------------------------------------------
char my_get_char() {
//1. We create the variable to be returned
char res = ' ';

//2. We create an extra variable to consume any other characters entered until a return is pressed
boolean line_consumed = False;
char dummy_char = ' ';

//3. We consume the first char entered, i.e., the one we are interested at
res = getchar();

//4. While still there are remaining characters
while (line_consumed == False) {
    //4.1. We consume the next character
    dummy_char = getchar();

    //4.2. If the new character is the end of line one, we can ensure we have consumed the entire line.
    if (dummy_char == '\n')
        line_consumed = True;
}

//5. We return res
return res;
}

//------------------------------------
//  06. FUNCTION is_position_empty 
//------------------------------------
boolean is_position_empty(game* g, int pos) {
//1. We create the variable to be returned
boolean res = False;

//2. We check if the index is a valid one and if the board is empty at that index.
//If it is valid and free, we return True. 
//Otherwise, we return False and write a warning message.
int row= pos/3;
int column = pos%3;

if (pos<0 || pos>8){
    printf("\t Invalid Position. Try again!\n\n");
    return res;
}
else if (g->board[row][column]=='X' || g->board[row][column]=='O'){
    printf("\t This postion is already busy. Try Again!\n\n");
    return res;
}
else{

    res=True;
    return res;
}

}

//---------------------------------------
//  07. FUNCTION user_get_movement_index 
//---------------------------------------
int user_get_movement_index(game* g) {

//2. We create a boolean variable to control that we have received a valid movement index. 
boolean validMove=False;

//3. We create a char variable to control the index we are receiving by keyboard.
char indexChar;
int indexInt;

//We print a message asking for a new movement. 
printf("         Enter a position 0 to 8: ");

//We call to my_get_char to get the index and we convert it to an integer. 
indexChar=my_get_char();
indexInt=indexChar-'0';

//We call to is_position_empty to check that the index is a valid one.
validMove=is_position_empty(g, indexInt);

  if (validMove==True)
      return indexInt;
  else
      return user_get_movement_index(g);
}
```

Working Correctly

[image: Working Correctly]

Working Correctly

[image: Working Correctly]

Looping

[image: Looping]

I have boolean defined as the following:

```
enum Bool { False, True };
typedef enum Bool boolean;
```

When I initialise all elements of the matrix as 'a', the problem still persists.
When a valid movement is entered, process_movement function is called and it initialises the corresponding element of board to either an 'X' or 'O'.

```
char mark;

if (g->status==1)
    mark='X';
else
    mark='O';

int row = pos/3;
int column = pos%3;

g->board[row][column]=mark;
```

By adding an extra printf within is_position empty, I can tell that the whole function is looping, but it seems to not be exiting is_position_empty as the printf from the function it returns to user_get_movement is not being printed. How is this possible? There is only a loop in user_get_movement and none in is_position_empty, and only loops for 0?

Comment: When the user types `'0'`, the program gets `48` (most probably).  You need to convert that to a number in the range 0..9 (by checking that it is a digit, and then subtracting `'0'` from the entered character).

Comment: Also please don't post pictures of the output, coy & paste the text and put it in your question.

Comment: I have subtracted ‘0’ in the code to convert from char to int

Comment: Error is not here.  Post [MCVE]

Comment: Have you properly initialized `g->board[][]`? Also, print the value of `indexChar` would help debugging (you may need `fflush(stdout)` after `printf`).

Comment: And how do you write user move in `g->board`?

Comment: please post how you are defining `True` and `False`.  IF using `stdbool.h`  the values are `true` and `false`  I.e no capitalization

Comment: the function: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: I have tried the proposed solution and it's still looping.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. is missing the `main()` function
2. is missing the function to determine if there was a winner and whom won
3. is missing the definition of `game`
4. does not have any unexpected looping
5. avoids the problem caused by having a 'recursive' function

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // getchar()
#include <stdbool.h> // bool, true, false
#include <ctype.h>   // isdigit()

// prototypes
int my_get_char( void );
bool is_position_empty(game* g, int pos);
int user_get_movement_index(game* g);


//--------------------------------------------------
// 05. FUNCTION my_getchar (IMPLEMENTED)
//--------------------------------------------------
int my_get_char()
{
    //1. We create the variable to be returned

    //3. We consume the first char entered, i.e., the one we are interested at
    int res = getchar();

    //4. While still there are remaining characters
    while ( '\n' != getchar() );

    //5. We return res
    return res;
}


//------------------------------------
//  06. FUNCTION is_position_empty
//------------------------------------
bool is_position_empty(game* g, int pos)
{
    //2. We check if the index is a valid one and if the board is empty at that index.
    //If it is valid and free, we return True.
    //Otherwise, we return False and write a warning message.
    int row= pos/3; = 0
    int column = pos%3; = 0

    if (pos<0 || pos>8)
    {
        printf("\t Invalid Position. Try again!\n\n");
        return false;
    }

    else if (g->board[row][column]=='X' || g->board[row][column]=='O')
    {
        printf("\t This postion is already busy. Try Again!\n\n");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


//---------------------------------------
//  07. FUNCTION user_get_movement_index
//---------------------------------------
int user_get_movement_index(game* g)
{
    //3. We create a char variable to control the index we are receiving by keyboard.
    int indexInt;

    do
    {
        //We print a message asking for a new movement.
        printf("         Enter a position 0 to 8: ");

        //We call to my_get_char to get the index and we convert it to an integer.
        indexInt = my_get_char();
        if( isdigit( indexInt ) )
        {
            indexInt -= '0';
        }

        else
        {
            printf( "entry was not in the inclusive range: 0...8\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //We call to is_position_empty to check that the index is a valid one.
    } while( !is_position_empty(g, indexInt) );

    return indexInt;
}
```